# Can staggered creatures still make extra attacks from the haste spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, attack, conditions

Let's suppose a player gets staggered just like being target of the   staggering critical feat for 3 rounds. But then she is hasted by a party member.

The question is: could she make the extra haste attack other than her only available due to the staggered condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[William Porter's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/141270/44723) is largely correct, but incomplete.

Haste grants an additional attack only on Full Attacks, not on the Attack Action (which is a Standard Action).

The Staggered condition restricts you to either a Standard Action or Move Action on your turn, and since that makes Full-Round Actions impossible you cannot use the Full Attack Action to make a Full Attack.

However, if you have other ways of making a Full Attack without using the Full Attack Action, you can still benefit from Haste and use your additional attack.

For example, while Staggered, you are allowed to perform a [Charge attack](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Charge&Category=Special%20Attacks) with only a Standard Action at a reduced movement. If you have the [Pounce ability](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Pounce) or something similar, you can still perform a Full Attack at the end of the Charge and then use the additional attack from the [Haste spell](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Haste).

Paizo released some FAQ regarding this:

- [Pounce and Haste](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fo#v5748eaic9r4l)
- [Pounce and Slow](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fo#v5748eaic9quy)

Answer (score 9):

### No.

[Haste](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste/) has the following line:

> When making a **full attack action**, a hasted creature may make one extra attack with one natural or manufactured weapon.

The [staggered](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions/#TOC-Staggered) condition states:

> A staggered creature may take a single move action or standard action each round (but not both, **nor can he take full-round actions**).

In the rules for [Full Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Full-Attack) we see:

> If you get more than one attack per round because your base attack bonus is high enough (see Base Attack Bonus in Classes), because you fight with two weapons or a double weapon, or for some special reason, **you must use a full-round action** to get your additional attacks.

Since Haste only grants it's extra attacks on a full attack which is a full round action, and the staggered condition prevents full round actions, they do not get to make the extra haste attack.